# What is the use of ModelState.ISValid even though it s validating in the client side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. While designing a Page i used Data Annotations as validations. I observed that all the validations already performed at the client side and i still didnt understood why i should use ModelState.IsValid in the server side also. I googled it but i am unable to understand it.
So will anyone suggest me when to use ModelState.IsValid as it is already validating in the client side.

Comment: Because a bad guy can craft an invalid message to the web app. Client side validation is optional, sever side is a must.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Haha.. true.. Client side validations can be manipulated and the bad guy can trespass to server. To avoid it we need to check in the server side too... Superb answer..

Comment: @shankar.parsanamoni i went through the link, but its not clearly related to my question.

Comment: Have a look here for more stuff you really need to know. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: If I disable JavaScript, I have successfully bypassed your validation. If I send the post request manually or from my own form, I have successfully bypassed your validation. It does not take much.

Comment: @AntP True.. Thank you for sharing the Javascript disable idea..

Comment: I like to think of client side validation as a user experience feature and server side validation as a security feature. One is optional (client side) just to improve the perceived performance of the app, the other one is a must (server side) to ensure you data is valid.
Its not just disabling JS to bypass it, you can use a browsers dev tools to bypass it or forego a browser altogether and post the data back to the server directly using something like JMeter or thousands of other HTTP tools.